# php validation not working

Tags: php, mysql, validation, error-handling

I am developing a simple registration form that validates with php. problem is rather than the validation echoing on screen once I click the submit button nothing happens, no error or brake it dose not show me what the error is, I believe my logic is correct but I believe there may be a mistake.

would appriciate any advise or identification of my problem

**register.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
        ),  
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
        ),  
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        echo 'Passed';
    }   else {
            print_r($validation->errors());
    }

}   
?>

<form action="" methord="post">
    <div class="field">
        <lable for="username">Username</lable>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <lable for="password">Choose Your Password</lable>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <lable for="password_again">Verify Password</lable>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <lable for="name">Your Name</lable>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo escape (Input::get('name')); ?>" id="name">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

**Validation.php**

```
   <?php
class Validate {
    private $_passed = false,
            $_errors = array(),
            $_db = null;

    public function __contruct() {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function check($source, $items = array()) {
        foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
            foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

                $value = $source[$item];

                if($rule == 'required' && empty($value)) {
                    $this->addError("{$item} is required")
                } else {

                }

            }
        }

        if(empty($this->_errors)) {
            $this->_passed = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    private function addError() {
        $this->_errors[] = $error;
    }

    public function errors() {
        return $this->_errors;
    }

    public function passed() {
        return $this->_passed;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Have corrected typo that was correctly pointed out by @PeteR, but there is still a problem that the echo validation is not printing out.

**Link to form**

http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~ob219/membership/register.php

Comment: //Turn your error reporting on to see what happens      ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
      error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Mubo Ok thanks great idea il give it a go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo, fella.

```
if($rule == 'requierd' && empty($value)) {
```

You also have a semicolon missing here:

```
$this->addError("{$item} is required");
                                  ----^
```

And another typo:

```
<form action="" methord="post">
```

Should be method...

And finally, try this:

```
private function addError($error) {
```

Comment: i before e except after c ... cheers @PeteR always something simple.

Comment: Either that, or you're just like me - crap at typing! :)

Comment: the spelling mistake has been corrected. unfortunately the echo that prints passed or tells the user what fields are missed is still not showing up.

Comment: thanks again, still not working though so I am going to scroll through the code try find the error

Comment: You should also take on board the stuff Dan posted, particularly the bit about enabling error reporting. Most of these errors would have thrown a warning and given you a pointer as to where to look... As a rule, always enable error reporting in a development environment, once the code is good then you should disable it again on the production server.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, not used debug in php before but I will give it a try in future, cheers @PeteR

Answer (score 1):

```
Input::exists()
```

returns false/null or contains errors, thus, the if statement is not `true`

```
if(Input::exists()) {
```

and the code inside of it (validation) does never get executed.

Debug with

```
print_r(Input::exists());
```

You should also change your if to a real condition:

```
if(Input::exists() === true) {
```

Enable error reporting in PHP (from http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/)

```
<?php
// Put these lines to the top of your script
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
ini_set('xmlrpc_errors', true);
```

Update - Yet another one:

```
private function addError() {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}
```

Method has no parameters..

```
private function addError($error) {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}
```

Comment: good advice, thank you ive not used that form of debug before has helped a lot.